# Is there a wrapper for `git-svn` that uses `svn` syntax?

Tags: git, svn, frontend

To which extent is this possible? And is there such a wrapper (or maybe front-end is more proper name)?

For example on how this would work. With `git-svn` you'd use `git svn clone <url>` instead of `svn co <url>` (IIRC), so here the wrapper would when `svn co <url>` is executed translate this and in reality do a `git svn clone <url>`.

Maybe this is a bad idea since there might be important cases that can't be handled (therefore the first question). Maybe this is a good idea (therefore the second question).

(Bonus question is if it's possible to do a similar thing based on `git` under some reasonable setup - that is a wrapper that makes `svn` users be able to use their accustomed commands while in reality they work against a `git` server).

The background is that we currently use `svn` and there are scripts (or makefiles) that make use of `svn` commands. My concern is that this fact would make it unsuitable to use `git-svn` (since then the scripts and makefiles will no longer work as expected).

(The bonus question can be viewed as a part of the argument for switching to `git`, if it were possible to continue using `svn` commands the counterargument stating that people would have to learn `git` won't be that strong.)

Comment: Do you have anything against learning the Git command line tools?  SVN and Git totally do not map 1:1 on each other.  @VonC might have something else to say here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, actually I prefer `git`. Otherwise it would be no point in using `git-svn`, is it? I realize of course that they don't map 1:1 and that's why I ask to which extent it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client) is to facilitate the transition from `svn` to `git`.

It accomplishes this goal by providing:

- a way to import an `Svn` repository into a local `Git` repository;
- a limited way to send the commits from the local `Git` repository back to the central `Svn` repository; it is limited because `Svn` provides only a limited subset of `Git` features and there are `Svn` features that are not provided by `Git`; also, there is no point for the `Git` team to work hard to make `git-svn` a complete `Svn` client because, as I said before, its purpose is to help the `Svn` users make the transition;
- a command line that resembles the command line of `Git`, with specific additions.

After using `git-svn` in the command line for some time you'll discover you already learned the most used `Git` commands.

---

The usage of `svn` in the existing scripts is, indeed, a legitimate reason to want a front-end for `git-svn` that mimics the command line of `svn`.

You have two options:

1. Write a wrapper script that accepts a command line using the `svn` options and converts it into a `git-svn` command line.
2. Modify the scripts to use `git-svn` instead of `svn`.

If you plan to migrate to `git` and `git-svn` is just an accommodation phase (this is how it should be) then you'll have to modify the scripts anyway to use `git` instead of `svn` in order to complete the migration.

A simple `bash` script that translates `svn` commands to `git-svn` commands could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SVN_CMD=$1
shift

# If $1 is empty then display some help
# ... not provided here ...

case "$SVN_CMD" in
  "checkout" )
    git svn clone "$@"
  ;;

  "update" )
    git svn fetch "$@"
  ;;

  "add" )
    git add "$@"
  ;;

  "commit" )
    git svn dcommit "$@"
  ;;
esac
```

For some of these commands you probably have to add extra options to match your current setup and workflow. Some of them probably don't need the `"$@"` part. **This is not a tested script, it is just a sketch I imagined now.**

---

A better option, I think, is to let the scripts use `svn` and their own working copy of the code (as `Svn` working copy) until the central repository is migrated to `Git`. The developers can use `git-svn` and local `Git` repositories until they decide it's the time to make the complete switch to `Git`.

This is how we did three years ago. Some developers needed an accommodation time and they used `git-svn` to close the gap; other developers jumped directly to `Git` command line or various `Git` GUI interfaces that hide the technical details (command line, for example) and let you focus on the code. A good `Git` GUI client is [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) besides many others.

When we eventually decided to switch to `Git` completely the scripts were easy to convert and test. Regarding the repositories, I recommend you try [`SubGit`](http://www.subgit.com) for conversion. It does a better job than `git-svn` does.